# Lost CONNECT privilege when upgrading postgres 14.5 to 14.8

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I have two Aurora clusters, both running one RDS instance but they are different instance families. Both were on Postgres 14.5:

- Cluster A: db.r5.2xlarge
- Cluster B: db.t3.medium

There is one IAM role on both servers, that is used to connect to the sevrvers. After upgrading to 14.8, cluster A no longer has `CONNECT` privilege for the role, but cluster B is working fine.

I ran the following statement

```
select * from has_database_privilege(<role_name>, <dbname>, 'CONNECT');
```

This confirms that CONNECT privilege is false in Cluster A, but true in Cluster B.

Issuing `GRANT CONNECT` for a database on Cluster A server will restore connectivity, but I am confused about what could have possibly caused this problem. All configurations for the servers are identical other than their instance family. Seems highly unlikely that a large instance class would behave differently on an update.

Comment: Sounds like a question for Amazon. Their upgrade process is not open source.